# Using indexes for math in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with a `checked_at` timestamp field and a `check_interval` integer field in PostgreSQL 9.4.

I need to return only the rows `WHERE checked_at > NOW() - INTERVAL check_interval || ' minutes'`

Would using a multicolumn index improve the speed of this query? Or is there some other way to optimize it?

The table is still in design, but ultimately expect to search through about 5-10 million records.

Comment: An index on `checkted_at` should be enough. If you have problems with a specific query, please read: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions

Comment: @horse_with_no_name I'm pretty sure index at `checked_at` is not enough if the expression is dependent on check_interval from the same row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A multicolumn index will not help you, however an index on expression will. If you change your query to:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl
WHERE (checked_at + (check_interval * (INTERVAL '1 minute'))) < NOW();
```

You can use an index

```
CREATE INDEX jbk_tbl_checkedat_checkinterval_ex ON tbl((checked_at + (check_interval * (INTERVAL '1 minute'))))
```